# a href URL refrescar o parar bucle

Tags: html, href

Estoy usando a href para un menu nav horizontal, el problema es que cada vez que se hace click en una categoria, se sobre pisan infinitamente.

Estoy intentando conseguir que cada vez que se haga click en el menu Juegos o Deportes, la url de la pagina se refresque y asi no haya una URL en bucle.

```
<a href="category/juegos-bundles/"><li>Juegos</li></a>
<a href="category/juegos-bundles/"><li>Deportes</li></a>
```

Ejemplo:

*www.ejemplo.com/juegos-bundles/juegos-bundles/juegos-bundles/*

Comment: Puedes poner código javascript en tu web ?

Comment: Si, la web soporta javascript

Comment: Hola, podrías mostrarnos el javascript, con el error q comentas?

Comment: Prueba cambiando la href a "/category/juegos-bundles/" (agregué un / al principio).

Comment: Gracias Victoria, definitivamente fue la mejor solución, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Para refrescar la pagina desde un link puedes usar esto

```
<a href="."><li>Juegos</li></a>
```

Comment: Pero si quito la referencia de href="." no puede acceder a la url indicada. Necesito meter la categoria dentro del href="category/juegos-bundles/"

Answer (score 1):

Añadiendo la barra inclinada /category/, delante de la URL, era el culpable del fallo.

Ejemplo Arreglado:

```
<a href="/category/juegos-bundles/"><li>Juegos</li></a>
```